# Recursive pyparsing of function invocation expression with args and kwargs

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am trying to create a parser using `pyparsing` that parses an expression of below formats:

```
FUNC_NAME(ARG1, ARG2, ..., ARGN, K1=V1, K2=V2, ..., KN=VN)
```

ARGs and KWARG values can be literals (quoted strings, numbers, a date expression without quotes) or itself be functions with infinite nesting.

The issue I can't seem to get past is the recursive structure with Forward().

Here is what I have:

```
import pyparsing as pp 

LP, RP = map(pp.Suppress, "()")
ident = ppc.identifier("ident")
number = pp.pyparsing_common.number
string = (pp.QuotedString("\"") | pp.QuotedString("'"))
date = pp.Combine(pp.Word(pp.nums, exact=4) + "-" + pp.Word(pp.nums, exact=2) + "-" + pp.Word(pp.nums, exact=2))("date")
literal = date | number | string

body = pp.Forward()
body <<= body | (ident + pp.Suppress("=") + body) | (ident + LP + body + RP) | literal | pp.empty
expr = ident + (LP + pp.Optional(pp.Group(pp.delimitedList(body))) + RP)
```

running this expression gives me a recursion depth error. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem, and props to you for getting started with a recursive grammar.

The immediate issue is in this definition of the contents of `body`:

```py
body <<= body | (ident + pp.Suppress("=") + body) | (ident + LP + body + RP) | literal | pp.empty
```

This creates a left-recursive (or "LR") expression, because to parse a `body` you first have to parse a `body`, but first you have to parse a `body`, but first... etc. The other alternative terms may also use `body`, but as part of a larger expression (after being enclosed in parentheses, or as part of an assignment). So the solution might be to just remove the leading `body` term:

```py
body <<= (ident + pp.Suppress("=") + body) | (ident + LP + body + RP) | literal | pp.empty
```

But you might have wanted to support enclosure of a `body` in parentheses, so changing to this would also resolve your LR issue:

```py
body <<= LP + body + RP | (ident + pp.Suppress("=") + body) | (ident + LP + body + RP) | literal | pp.empty
```

Either of these changes will resolve your LR issue. By default, pyparsing does not support LR parsers. You *can* enable this, using a feature that was added in pyparsing 3.0.0:

```py
pp.ParserElement.enable_left_recursion()
```

But with either of the suggested changes, it would not be necessary.

I also added these lines, to generate a railroad diagram of your parser. I've found these diagrams to be very helpful in visualizing the parser's structure;

```py
pp.autoname_elements()
expr.create_diagram("lr_function_parser.html")
```

Which generated this diagram:

[image: railroad diagram for the OPs parser]

Good luck in your further pyparsing work!

Comment: Thanks very much for getting back! This is very helpful. 
I'm now almost getting there, I can parse below expression:

`res = expr.parseString("A(B(c=7), dates=123)")`

but for instance this one still fails:

`res = expr.parseString("A(B(), d=C('abc', 'def'))")`

`ParseException: Expected ')', found 'C'  (at char 9), (line:1, col:10)`

Answer (score 0):

When I've had to write parsers like this that required recognition of function calls, I usually defined a specific expression for function calls, and then included them as an option in my base operand or expression Like this:

```py
# using previous definitions for ident, literal, etc.
EQ = pp.Suppress("=")
expr = pp.Forward()
fn_arg = ident + EQ + expr | expr
fn_call = pp.Group(ident + pp.Group(LP + pp.Optional(pp.delimited_list(fn_arg)) + RP))
expr <<= fn_call | literal | ident | pp.Group(LP + expr + RP)
```

Where `expr` takes the place of your `body`. From this diagram, see how this work compared to the above:

[image: railroad diagram of new parser]